# How to plot frequency vs time graph of an audio signal/recording?

Tags: acoustics

I need to plot a frequency variation with time graph for an audio signal that I will record, to observe the variation in frequency with time. I'm completely new to audio signal analysis and have no experience with any related software or matlab. I'd really appreciate some info on the simplest software to use for making such a plot with least the amount of technical knowledge required. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

One of the simplest ways to observe frequency variation with respect to time is called a **spectrogram**.  This type of plots stacks Fourier spectra together into an image that looks very much like a heat map.
These are built-in to a number of software packages.  You can use the FREE (and reasonably user-friendly!) audio editing program called `Audacity` to view your signal's spectrogram.  Here is a link to using that functionality:

http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/spectrogram_view.html

When you do start using something like MATLAB for your tasks, you will find spectrogram tools readily available and very easy to use as well.  MATLAB's tool is called just that, 'spectrogram'.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but spectrograms plot energy vs frequency, not frequency vs time - the OP is asking for the latter. Nevertheless, `audacity` is the *right* answer :-)

Comment: @Nick, in this case, it's actually the combination of all 3!  A **spectrogram** will perform a series of short-time Fourier transforms over a specific window size, such that the user can observe changes in the frequency distribution and, by extension, the dominant frequency (e.g., a note being played) over time.  Technically, energy vs. frequency is the **Energy Spectral Density**, or, in the vernacular, the **Spectrum** or the **FFT** (although the latter is just a technique, an approximation of the actual Fourier transform).